# Bottom Navigation bar in android studio with java

Tags: android-studio

when compiling my program i send an error at the level of the switch cases id objects of the bottom navigation bar  in the mainActivity.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
public class about extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.about_button);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home_button:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    finish();
                    return true;
                case R.id.agence_button:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), agence.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    finish();
                    return true;
                case R.id.reserve_button:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), about.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    finish();
                    return true;
                case R.id.about_button:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

[here is the MainActivity with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojp8G.png) 
[error send a the MainActivity after compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7EsS.png)]

i tried to declared the value as it suggested to me it was just worst

Answer (score 0):

with newer versions of Android, the id for every component is acting more like a variable than a constant, and you cannot use them for switch-case just like a regular primitive variable will fail for you.
to make this code scope work you generally have you have two choices:

first choice:
migrate to if, if else. in your case:

```
if(item.getItem() == R.id.home_button){

}else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.agence_button){

}else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.reserve_button){

}else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.about_button){

}
```

second choice:
make a final int for every id

```
final int HOME = R.id.home_button;
final int AGENCE = R.id.agence_button;
final int RESERVE = R.id.reserve_button;
final int ABOUT = R.id.about_button;
switch(item.getItemId()){
    case HOME:
    //your code
    case AGENCE:
    //your code
    case RESERVE:
    //your code
    case ABOUT:
    //your code
}
```

by the way, from the context of your given code, I recommend setting every page\screen as a fragment and collecting them all in an activity that hosts the bottom navigation bar.

good luck with your app!